# Coffee loiters in the breakroom

Tags: break-time

I am a huge coffee drinker in the office, as in I drink maybe a two pots a day. Recently, we've acquired another company and they have moved them into our office. What I've noticed is how great they are at never refilling the coffee machine. At first, a few others and I confronted them and of course they apologized.

Well things have gotten a lot worse. They've went from simply not refilling the coffee pot (the push ones where you can't see into it), to being the masters of being the second to the last one to empty it. They done it all, from slowly pushing the handle until the stream weakens, to "accidentally" touching the pots to see which one feels empty, to waiting nearby until someone refills the pot.

I want to know, how can I stop these people from doing this? I've tried to get others to join me, but nobody seems to care but me.

Comment: Why can't you just refill the pot when you find it is empty?

Comment: Do you folks pay for coffee/filters/sugar/milk-cream and other stuff? Or is it provided by the company?

Comment: @teego1967: *Why can't you just refill the pot when you find it is empty?* -> for the same exact reason your SO would complain if they have to wash all the dirty dishes at home, every single day, with the two of you cooking and eating, maybe? ;)

Comment: @teego1967 - Having to wait for the pot to be filled every time you need a cup of coffee wastes more time.

Comment: By the way, what do you think 'loiters' means?

Comment: Somewhere out there on the internet there's probably a forum post along the lines of, *"We just merged with a new company and there's this guy there who drinks like TWO WHOLE POTS OF COFFEE every day and he acts like it's OUR problem the coffee pot is sometimes empty, when all we want is a cup or two in the morning!!!!"*

Comment: Why do you think [webcams were invented](https://gizmodo.com/5993583/the-worlds-first-webcam-was-created-to-check-a-coffee-pot-remotely)? So people don't have to stand up an walk to an empty coffee pot

Answer (score 16):

Congratulations, you've encountered one of the downsides of two groups of people starting to share a space. And the downside is...people suddenly start obsessing over little things, like who refills the coffee pot.

These people are new and disrupting your well-ordered existence. In your office, you expect the person who emptied the coffee pot to refill it. In their previous office maybe it was assumed that whoever wanted coffee made it. Or maybe someone was given the job of making the coffee. Or maybe everybody was too busy with work to worry about it. In any case, you area having to establish new norms in a new situation. You've clearly started this by 'confronting them'. (Though is confrontation always the best way? How would you react if you moved to a new office, did whatever you normally did with the coffee, and someone chewed you out for it?)

So relax, wait for new norms to be developed, have polite non-confrontational conversations about the way to do things with the newcomers and everything will settle down, and you can get back to the point where everyone is too busy doing valuable work to worry about the coffee.

Comment: Perhaps OP is making too big of a deal of this but this is essentially a non-answer. The "new norms" that will be established by doing nothing is that some people will always have to make coffee and others will take advantage. That doesn't seem like a good resolution. If your answer is essentially "You should also learn to stop caring." you may want to make that more explicit.

Comment: @Lilienthal This is perhaps the best possible answer to the "empty coffee carafe" caper. Attempting to initiate _anything_ even remotely along the lines of instituting a "official coffee policy" will be perceived as petty and reflect badly on the OP.

Comment: I think this wouldn't be a great IPS answer, but for the workplace its a good one.  One thing I have learnt in shared spaces is to pick your battles (and most things are worth letting go....)

Comment: @Lilienthal makes the best point, in part, that some people will always have to make the coffee and others will take advantage. This will happen regardless of any new policies or practices, because these interactions do not change. It doesn't matter if your stockroom always has empty boxes and you're the one who always tosses them or if you always have to go find more pens because people drain your supply. In fact the best thing to do would be to engineer out the problem completely. In this case, you have your teams coffee pot that you fill, and they have theirs. One will always be empty.

Comment: i.e. request a coffee maker for your team *only*.

Answer (score 3):

If only we could have an [office linebacker (American Football).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5dJb2YG7vU)

Since you don't, buy a thermos and fill it with several cups of coffee at a time. This will reduce trips to the coffee maker for you, so you won't have to suffer these fools too often.

Some people will complain, but make sure you show them you start a new pot. You wouldn't have to do this if everyone did their part.

I would be the office linebacker for free.